# What is the intuition behind the defintion of the degree of a field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, intuition

Longtime lurker and a first time poster.

This question has been bugging me A LOT, and I couldn't find many relevant posts about my question. To give more context I have been wanting to study the theory of field and extensions and ultimately Galois theory. Then I started using Dummite and Foote's treatment of it(From there abstract algebra book) and they didn't especially give much intuition behind the definition of the degree of a field extension. Adding examples to your answers is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It‘s just saying how much larger $L$ than $K$ is in a field extension $L/K$. If you read D&F, then surely they will provide a lot of elementary examples, it should become immediately apparent.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have an inclusion $K\subset L$ of fields the larger field $L$ has a natural structure of vector space over the smaller field $K$.

Indeed $L$ is an abelian addtive group with a multiplication by elements in $K$ and the vector space axioms follow at once frm the fact that $L$ is a field and elements of $K% are also elements of $L$.

Then one defines the degree of the extension as the dimension of $L$ as $K$-vector space:
$$
[L:K]=\dim_K(L).
$$
This (possibly infinite) value is a raw index of complexity of the field $L$ relatively to $K$.

Its knowledge gives some information, for instance if $[L:K]=n$ we know that every element $z\in L$ satisfies a polynomial relation
$$
P(z)=0
$$
where $P(X)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $K$ of degree $\leq n$.

Conversely, if $P(X)$ is an **irreducible** polynomial with coefficients in $K$ of degree $n$ and $z$ is a root, then the set
$$
L=\{a_0+a_1z+\cdots a_{n-1}z^{n-1}\,|\,a_i\in K\}
$$
is actually a field containing $K$ such that $[L:K]=n$ (this example is very relevant for arithmetic).